# Monitorar processamento de script PHP

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, http-headers, progress-bar

Alguém conhece uma forma de monitorar o processamento de código PHP e apresentar no cliente?

Estou projetando um conversor de *layout* que pega arquivos de dados num determinado formato e converte para outro formato.

Basicamente, gostaria de apresentar para o usuário (no navegador cliente), uma barra de progresso com a evolução do processamento dos arquivos no servidor. Esse processamento não é o andamento do *upload* (isso faço com `XMLHTTPRequest`), mas o andamento da conversão.

Já tentei fazer setando um *cookie* com `setcookie` e `setrawcookie` no PHP a cada 10% processados e tentando pegar o valor do *cookie* com Javascript no lado do cliente, também a cada 1 segundo com `setInterval()`, mas parece que o PHP envia todos os *cookies* de uma vez após o processamento do *script*, e não no momento em que `setcookie()` é chamada.

Também tentei usar `header()` em vez de `setcookie` e também os *header* enviados somente aparecem no cliente após o processamento completo do *script*.
O início do processamento no servidor eu tenho feito com `XMLHTTPRequest` para a página que faz o processamento.

Também tentei com iframe, fazendo o processamento rodar no iframe e tentando pegar cookies dele na página principal, mas não tive sucesso.
Consegui monitorar usando um arquivo de texto onde o php grava o progresso e leio ele através do Ájax. Porém, parece que só funciona com o php safe thred

Comment: Você pode apresentar um serviço PHP que retorna somente o progresso. Seu cliente acessaria a URL para buscar o valor.

Comment: Tipo assim: o script php que faz a conversão fica salvando o progresso num banco de dados ou arquivo no servidor. O cliente, fica fazendo requisições para outro script que fica lendo o progresso desse banco de dados/arquivo?

Comment: Eu gosto de usar o Gearman para essas coisas. http://br1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/gearmanclient.addtaskstatus.php

Comment: Não conhecia. Tem também esta técnica: http://rberaldo.com.br/server-push-long-polling-php-ios/

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo a sugestão do RSinohara consegui implementar a lógica usando XMLHTTPRequest, file_put_contents e file_get_contents.

O arquivo index.php cria dois XMLHTTPRequest: um para o arquivo process.php que faz o processamento dos dados e salva o progresso em progress.txt (o código é apenas didático) e outro para o progress.php, que lê o progresso do progress.txt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function run(){
                var progressbar = document.getElementById('progresso');
                console.log('progressbar carregada');

                var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                console.log('xhr1 criada');
                xhr1.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    console.log('xhr1: state=' + xhr1.readyState + ' status=' + xhr1.status);
                    if(xhr1.readyState == 4 && xhr1.status == 200){
                        console.log(xhr1.responseText);
                    }
                }
                xhr1.open('GET', 'process.php', true);
                console.log('xhr1.open');
                xhr1.send();
                console.log('xhr1.send');

                var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                console.log('xhr2 criada');
                var progress = 0;
                xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    console.log('xhr2: state=' + xhr2.readyState + ' status=' + xhr2.status);
                    if(xhr2.readyState == 4 && xhr2.status == 200){
                        console.log('progresso: ' + xhr2.responseText);
                        progress = xhr2.responseText;
                        progressbar.value = progress;
                    }
                }

                while(progress < 100){
                    xhr2.open('GET', 'progress.php', false);
                    console.log('xhr2.open para progresso ' + progress);
                    xhr2.send();
                    console.log('xhr2.send para progresso ' + progress);
                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="run()">Iniciar</button>
        <progress max="100" id="progresso" value="0"></progress>
    </body>
</html>
```

O arquivo process.php (código apenas didático)

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', '3600');

if(@file_exists('progress.txt')){
    @unlink('progress.txt');
}

for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i += 20){
    sleep(3);
    file_put_contents('progress.txt', $i);
}
echo 'Terminou!';
```

Arquivo progress.php

```
<?php

if(@file_exists('progress.txt')){
    echo file_get_contents('progress.txt');
}else{
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: Aparentemente, no Windows, o PHP Non Thread Safe não trabalha bem com isso. Ele envia os dados tudo ao final. Já com o PHP Thread Safe, parece funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

É possível vincular uma função ao evento *progress* de `XMLHttpRequest`, nela é preciso verificar se é possível calcular o tamanho da resposta, que é recebido através do cabeçalho *"Content-Length"*.

Para que o PHP possa enviar o conteúdo durante o processamento é preciso ligar *flush* implicito, desligar o *buffer* de saída e a compactação gzip. **As configurações que coloquei no `.htaccess` [não podem ser alteradas com `ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/outcontrol.configuration.php)**.

---

#### HTML/JavaScript

```
<div id="progresso"></div>
<script>
var mensagem = document.getElementById('progresso');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) { // é possível calcular progresso
        mensagem.textContent = parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100) + '% concluído';
    } else { // remove evento para não repetir chamada
        xhr.removeEventListener('progress', arguments.callee, false);
        mensagem.textContent = 'não é possível calcular progresso';
    }
}, false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
    if (this.readyState !== 4) return;
    if (this.status === 200) {
        alert('requisição concluída');
    } else {
        mensagem.textContent = 'erro';
    }
};
xhr.open('POST', 'progresso.php', true);
xhr.send();
</script>
```

#### .htaccess

```
php_value output_buffering Off
```

#### progresso.php

```
<?php
// desligar compressão gzip
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1); // apenas para Apache
// ativar flush implícito
ini_set('implicit_flush', 'On'); // ou ob_implicit_flush(1);

$length = 100; // etapas de processamento
header('Content-Length: ' . $length); // tamanho da resposta
for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
    // aguardar 0.2 segundos - simulando execução de tarefa
    usleep(200000);
    // exibir 1 caractere por tarefa concluída
    echo '.';
}
```