# Executar ate o final processos de longa duração

Tags: php

Pessoal estou com dificuldade para que minha aplicação execute ate o final, sendo que ela mostra todo o processo em tempo real na tela utilizando `XMLHttpRequest | onprogress` e após cerca de pouco mais de 2hrs em execução o navegador simplesmente para.

meu script está assim:

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);


while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
ob_implicit_flush();

// vários processos
echo "process..."
```

Já pesquisei MUITO a respeito e muito se fala em PHP [CLI](http://php.net/features.commandline.usage), fiz um teste com [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php) mas o mesmo não exibe em tempo real conforme acima os processos.

Alguém já passou por isso? tem alguma solução?

Comment: Você pode usar redirect durante o processo?

Comment: @DavidJonas onde posso buscar mais informações sobre `redirect` ? teria alguma ideia de implementação? :)

Comment: @smigol qual intuito deste deste código?

Comment: Faço isso numa aplicação, utilizei [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78748/13561), o processo dura +/- 1h e acontece sem erros. Conforme o [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/outcontrol.configuration.php) `output_buffering` não pode ser configurado com `ini_set()`, a configuração deve ser feita no `.htaccess` com `php_value output_buffering Off`.

Comment: Pela descrição parece que o problema é no navegador, não no PHP, você conseguiu alguma mensagem de erro no console do navegador ou o navegador simplesmente "trava"? Tente monitorar o XHR pela [aba network](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)