# Splashscreen em php

Tags: php

Como fazer uma tela de carregamento que aguarde um período de X segundos para fazer uma determinada ação. Ex: Executando uma `Query` no banco de dados...

Ex:

```html
  <?php 
    $outTime = 1000; // tempo em ms
    ...
  ?>

<div id="splash">Aguarde...</div>
<div id="conteudo">Sucesso!</div>
```

Comment: você usa jquery em sua aplicação?

Comment: não. é puro php!

Comment: php é sincronizado e roda do lado do servidor ou seja é http, a resposta é só renderizada após o download parcial ou completo do documento. A operação que você quer deve ser feita no front-end. Outra coisa `int outTime` não é PHP.

Comment: é tipo eu executo `function a() { return "teclaA"; }`  e ele espera um tempo em X segundos para realizar a ação.

Comment: É só para com que não carregue tudo diretamente.

Comment: Então @Nathan1302 o php não manipula o DOM no momento em que ele esta no Navegador (pois o PHP é uma linguagem que executa em servidores, diferente do javascript)! Poderia considerar fazer isso com jQuery, fazendo uma chamada via ajax.

Comment: ah ta! eu pensava que o dom era manipulado também pelo mesmo!

Comment: E no caso do jquery como seria?

Comment: pergunta relacionada [Monitorar processamento de script PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78748/13561)